# Display Configurable Product Image to Match Filter Selection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have a configurable product, it has 2 colour options - black and white.

When I navigate to its category on my website I see my products black version thumbnail, which is an image I have manually selected as thumbnail when I created the configurable product.

Now I select colour white in the magento layered filter on left hand side and only products have white option (one of the configurable product variations) shown, but thumbnail hasn't changed, its still what I have manually selected previously. I would like the image that I have attached to white option of this product to be displayed.

Now the question is how to get this thumbnail to change according to filter selection?